# How to align a paragraph exactly from the top of page, not from the bottom of last paragraph?

Tags: vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe,nohead]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\vspace*{130pt}\par
\huge{Sartor Resartus}
\clearpage
\epigraph{\begin{otherlanguage}{german}Mein Vermächtniß, wie herrlich weit und breit!  \endgraf Die Zeit ist mein Vermächtniß, mein Acker ist die Zeit.\end{otherlanguage}}{Goethe}\par
\vspace{130pt}
\huge{Sartor Resartus}
\end{document}
```

I want same spaces from the top for Headings on both pages. But I don't know how to set them.

[image: Positioning exactly from the top of page]

Comment: I would say, this depends on the used document class... which is ... please fill in yourself;-)

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence, it's done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the epigraph in a zero height minipage:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe,nohead]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}% not a very good idea
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\vspace*{130pt}
\huge Sartor Resartus

\endgroup

\clearpage

\begingroup

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\textwidth}
\epigraph{%
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{german}
  Mein Vermächtniß, wie herrlich weit und breit!\endgraf
  Die Zeit ist mein Vermächtniß, mein Acker ist die Zeit.
  \end{otherlanguage*}}{Goethe}%
\end{minipage}

\vspace{130pt}
\huge Sartor Resartus

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Note that `\huge` *doesn't* take an argument. You'll probably use `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepage}` instead of my `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @egreg! Could you explain please, why the line \setlength{\topskip}{0pt} isn't good idea? It's very useful for titlesec chapter headings alignment.

Comment: @web-stranger That might be, but it can have undesired consequences in other cases.